# React functions arent getting invoked in a functional component

Tags: reactjs, react-functional-component

import  { useState } from 'react'

import { AiOutlinePlus } from 'react-icons/ai'

import { TimerForm } from './TimerForm'

export const ToggleAddTimer = () => {

const [formState, setFormState] = useState(false);

const handleFormOpen = () => {

```
setFormState(true);
```

}

const handleFormClose = () => {

```
setFormState(false);
```

}

if (formState) {

```
return (

  <TimerForm formClose={handleFormClose()} />

)
```

}

else {

```
return (

  <button onClick={() => {handleFormOpen()}}> this function isn't getting invoked
    <AiOutlinePlus/>
  </button>
)
```

}
}

Answer (score 0):

Try `<TimerForm formClose={handleFormClose} />`

and in your else

```
<button onClick={() => handleFormOpen()}>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
const [formState, setFormState] = useState(false)

const toggleFormState = () => {
  setFormState(state => !state);
}

<button onClick={toggleFormState}> 
   <AiOutlinePlus/>
</button>
```

Test:

```
function App() {
  
  const [formState, setFormState] = useState(false)
  
  const toggleFormState = () => {
     setFormState(state => !state);
  }

  return (
      <button onClick={toggleFormState}>
          Form State is {formState ? "true": "false"}
      </button>
  )
}
```